# Storing objects to localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

My domain is quite simple. I have a `Message` class, and a `MessagesManager` class.

`Message` has 3 attributes:

1. `author`
2. `message` (body)
3. `timestamp`

`MessagesManager` is basically just an interface that keeps the history of messages, adds new messages etc.

I want to store the messages in `localStorage` so that they can be retrieved at later points, yet I'm not sure how to do it.

```
class MessagesManager {
    constructor() {
        this.msgs = []; //retrieve from localStorage
    }

    add(author, message) {
        var msg = new Message(author, message)
        this.msgs.push(msg);
    }

    save() {
        // save to localStorage
    }

    delete() {
        this.msgs = [];
    }
}
```

And my `Message`:

```
class Message {
    constructor(author, message) {
        this.timestamp = Date.now();
        this.author = author;
        this.message = message;
    }

    toString() {
        var date = new Date(this.timestamp);

        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();

        if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;

        var time = "[" + [hours, minutes, seconds].join(":") + "]";

        return time + " " + this.author + ": " + this.message;
    }
}
```

What is the nicest/best way to store the messages (as objects, kind of) in the `localStorage`, while also being able to retrieve them easily (ie. in `MessagesManager` contructor)?

Comment: this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MessagesManager {
   constructor() {
      this.msgs = (localStorage.getItem("messages"))?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messages")):[];
}

add(author, message) {
    var msg = new Message(author, message)
    this.msgs.push(msg);
}

save() {
    localStorage.setItem("messages", JSON.stringify(this.msgs));
}

delete() {
    this.msgs = [];
    localStorage.removeItem("messages");
}
```

}

Docs: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp